# PHP - foreach duplicates values through iterations

Tags: php, foreach, duplicates, laravel-4

I am currently building a Laravel theme manager and im stuck a bit.

So i have a `themes` folder containing other folders for the actual theme files , these folders contain a `template.php`as well, what contain basic data, `name`, `title`, `description`, `version`, and `author`

Made a function what checks for a match if the actual theme exsits in the database, if yes ignor reading the `template.php,` if not read the folder for that actual theme and store the file content in the database, after cliking install.

All works fine, if there is only one theme details stored in the database, if i install a second it turns back all themes located in the `theme` folder, checked and fround if there are more than data stored in the database, it duplicates the results.

**Code**

```
protected $theme_path = 'app/themes';

protected $manifest = 'template.php';

public function notInstalledThemes()
{
    $themes = $this->all();

    // get all directories form theme folder 
    $directories = File::directories($this->theme_path);

    // replace back slash to forward slash
    $directories = str_replace('\\', '/', $directories);

    foreach ($themes as $theme) 
    {
        
        foreach ($directories as $directory) 
        {
            // we dont need the admin
            // and ignor the themes already installed
            if ($directory != $this->theme_path.'/admin' && $directory != $this->theme_path.'/'.$theme->name)
            {
                $notINstalled = File::getRequire($directory.'/'.$this->manifest);

                $data[] = $notINstalled;
            } 
            
        }

    }

    if (!empty($data)) return $data;
}
```

So if i only have one theme stored in the database i and `var_dump` the results in my second foreach all fine

**for one data**

```
 foreach ($directories as $directory) 
    {
        var_dump($directory);
        // we dont need the admin
        // and ignor the themes already installed
        if ($directory != $this->theme_path.'/admin' && $directory != $this->theme_path.'/'.$theme->name)
        {
            $notINstalled = File::getRequire($directory.'/'.$this->manifest);
    
            $data[] = $notINstalled;
        } 
    
}
```

**out puts**

```
string(16) "app/themes/admin"
string(17) "app/themes/cosmos"
string(18) "app/themes/default"
```

i get back the directories fine,

But if another theme data is stored in the database the iteration duplicates the results

**second out puts**

```
string(16) "app/themes/admin"
string(17) "app/themes/cosmos"
string(18) "app/themes/default"
string(16) "app/themes/admin"
string(17) "app/themes/cosmos"
string(18) "app/themes/default"
```

Searched the net, found [array_unique](https://www.php.net/function.array-unique)

but did not really work, could anybody please give me a hint on how to avoid this?

Comment: Reorganize your logic: first, build an array of *installed theme directories*, then iterate over the *array of filesystem directories* and find the entries that are not present in the first array.

Comment: Sorry im to sleepy, so actually i did what you just told, the first foreach goes over the installed themes, and the second loop is to check the representation

Answer (score 1):

When you have two themes in your database, your code is doing the following:

```
$themes = $this->all();
// Assuming you have admin and cosmos in your db:
// $themes = ['admin', 'cosmos']

$directories = File::directories($this->theme_path);
// $directories = ['admin', 'cosmos', 'default']
```

So, the loops are running like this:

```
foreach ($themes as $theme) 
{
    // 2 iterations: 'admin' and 'cosmos'
    foreach ($directories as $directory) 
    {
        // 3 iterations: 'admin', 'cosmos', and 'default'
```

Which is why you are having the output that you described (2x3 iterations).

The piece remaining, in order to have unique entries in your `$data` array, is something like the following, which uses PHP [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/in_array) function.

```
if ($directory != $this->theme_path.'/admin' && $directory != $this->theme_path.'/'.$theme->name)
{
    $notINstalled = File::getRequire($directory.'/'.$this->manifest);
        
    if ( ! in_array($notInstalled, $data))
    {
        $data[] = $notINstalled;
    }
}
```

Comment: one question, in_array($notInstalled, $data) here the data variable is not defiend above before the if check, that only stores the returned values, this way it will just return an error, why i need to define it there?

Comment: The first time the `in_array` function is executed, `$data` is null so it will throw an error. You can either declare it before the loops with `$data = array()` or add `is_array($data)` to this conditional. I'd suggest the first one, as it will perform better.

Comment: nvm, sat down today and recoded the whole logic, thanks for your time and patience